# Best practices to handle JSON data for API SDK

Tags: php

The company I work for has an API and I am porting that API over to PHP. Right now, the API returns to me a large JSON object and I'm trying to figure out how I should handle the data.  I could have a whole bunch of "get" methods, like:

```
$t = new APIThing();
$t->getJSONObjects();
for ($i=0; ...) {
   $t->getHeadline($i);
}
```

Or, I could return the JSON object and let people play with the data themselves, so that would be something like this

```
$t = new APIThing();
$t->getJSONObjects();
foreach ($t as $u) {
    echo $u->headline;
}
```

So what do you think?  Just expose the JSON object or wrap the whole thing up into functions?

Comment: Usually the second approach is simpler. If you do not plan to change the behavior of the headline getter then it is safe to not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of that you can have a class that gets anything from the JSON

```
class GETAPI {

   protected $api;

   function __construct(){
        $this->api = new APIThing();
        $this->api->getJSONObjects();
   }

   function getAllFromAPI($name){
       foreach($this->api as $u){
           echo $u->$name;
       }
   }

   //or :
   function getFromAPI($name, $index){
       return $this->api[$index]->$name;
   }

}
```

its rudimentary and could use some work, but that work over making many many get functions

than all you would have to do is something like:

```
$api = new GETAPI();

$api->getAllFromAPI('headline');
//or
echo $api->getFromAPI('headline', 1); // with one as the array index
```

Comment: I was sort of thinking of this approach too...just using the PHP magic __call() function...but there are objects within objects and I think this might get a little complex

Comment: possibly, also: i forgot `$this` in my example, i added it in

Comment: ahhh i also ddnt see that ur object was ina loop, one sec ill fix the code

Comment: @JoeC, i now made 2 seperate functions in the call, one to get all from api and the other only to get an index